# Extracting data from nested json file

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

This is the schema of the data and wanted to extract 'from' in this.
Tried using the
df3 =df.select(df.transcript.data.from.alias("Type"))
and getting invalid syntax error.

How to extract this.

```
root
 |-- contactId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- mediaLegId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- transcript: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- action: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- chatId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- customerInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- customerIdentifierToken: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- customerIdentifierType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- customerName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- initialQuestion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- entryPoint: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- parkDuration: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- parkNote: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- participant: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- disconnectReason: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- participantId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- preferences: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- language: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- userName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- reconnected: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- relatedData: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- transcriptText: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- transferNote: string (nullable = true)
```

|    |    |    |-- transcriptText: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- transferNote: string (nullable = true)

Comment: can you share sample data

Answer (score 1):

Try using it like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(F.explode("transcript").alias('transcript')).select('transcript.*').select("data.*").select("from").show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response  Amit this works if I just need only that column, is there any way that I can use that in combination with other attributes as well?

Tried this 
sample1_2 =df.select(df.contactId.alias("ContactId"),\
               df.select(F.explode("transcript").alias('transcript')).select('transcript.*').select("data.*").select("from"),\
               df.transcript.data.participant.participantId.alias("participantId"),\
               
               df.transcript.data.text.alias("text")
               
            
).toDF('contactId','Type','participantId','Transcript')

Comment: Got this error :

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[from: string] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: Try this : df.select("contactId", F.explode("transcript").alias('transcript')).select("contactId", 'transcript.*').select("contactId", "data.*").select("contactId", "from", "text", "participant.*").select("contactId", "from", "text", "participantId").show()